# How to check value of Datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Datatable. I want to check corresponding value with it. It has two columns User and password. I want to check what password is correspond to User.

```
if (dt.Rows[cbxuserid.SelectedIndex]["Password"] == txtpass.Text && dt.Rows[cbxuserid.SelectedIndex]["Uname"] == txtid.Text)
            {
                ub.deleteuser(cbxuserid.SelectedText, txtpass.Text);

            }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a request to write code for him/her. Please show what have you tried and what is going wrong

Comment: Hopefully the username and password is on a same row, and hopefully you don't have password in plain text :)

Comment: Just loop through your datatable rows (alternative: use linq select) and check for the username. if you found the corresponding row use your decrypt mechanism on the row["PasswordColumn"]. Here's an article which describes everything you need to know: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y06xa2h1.aspx

Comment: I have updated code.Will this work haven't tried it though.